# Graph theory: Trail with only the last vertex repeated

Tags: graph-theory

In an open trail, vertices may repeat and edges cannot. In a closed trail (or circuit), start and end vertices are the only ones that can repeat.

So, what is the proper definition of a trail where only the end vertex can repeat? For example, ABCDB in the following graph.

```
  E
  |
  B _ D
 / \ /
A   C
```

Answer (score 1):

A trail is a walk that does not pass over the same edge twice. A trail might visit the same vertex twice, but only if it comes and goes from a different edge each time.
A path is a walk that does not include any vertex twice, except that its first vertex might be the same as its last.[check this](http://www.edmath.org/MATtours/discrete/concepts/cwalk.html)

A circuit is a trail that begins and ends on the same vertex.

(A-B-C-D-B) is a trail between A and B.
(C-D-B-C) is a circuit .
Also check this:[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory))